# Is there a meta for Stack Overflow Jobs?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs, meta

Is there a meta for Stack Overflow Jobs?

If there is not (and I cannot find one) should there be a meta for Stack Overflow Jobs?

If there should not be (and I can see arguments both for and against) where might I ask a meta question about finding employment based on the skills I have learned and developed on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yeah, right here. Just use the [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) tag.

Comment: @Rounin to be clear; that tag is for bugs, features and support for the actual jobs product. It's not a tag for soliciting career advice which is what you seem to be asking? There is no meta for that particular topic and I doubt there will be.

Comment: Thanks, no worries. I've been de facto unemployed / underemployed since my business collapsed in late 2008. All attempts to revive my business (business coaching / investment / employing others) from 2009-2015 failed, though there have been many useful lessons along the way. I've spent a lot of time since 2012 learning a whole new skillset (php, javascript, jquery, SVG, regex, Ajax, JSON etc.) - I am indebted to SO for providing an environment where such is possible. However the manner in which I might translate increasingly competent skills into an actual position has - thus far - eluded me.

Answer (score 10):

There is of course also [workplace.stackexchange.com](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which may be of use for career-related questions